# Add full meta to WordPress images

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm calling image into `single.php` with the following code to add CSS

**single.php**

```
<? if( has_post_thumbnail( $post_id ) ): ?>
    <div class="post-image">
        <img src="<?=wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id() ); ?>">
    </div>
<? endif; ?>
```

The problem is that I now find that the meta data added through the CMS side when I click on edit media isn't showing.

Does anyone know how to code them into my `single.php`?

**my full single.php**

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<? if( has_post_thumbnail( $post_id ) ): ?>
    <div class="single-featured-image post-image">
        <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
        <img src="<?=wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id() ); ?>">
    </div>
<? endif; ?>

<img src="<?php echo $url; ?>" />

    <div class="blog-post">
            <?php
            if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
                get_template_part( 'content-single', get_post_format() );

                if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) :
                    comments_template();
                endif;

            endwhile; endif;
            ?>
    </div>
</div> // closes of container

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: What "meta" precisely do you want to display? Is not that you are losing it, but that you aren't displaying at all.

Comment: title description and alt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the "alt" attribute you need to use `get_post_meta` for the attachment id. But for **title** and **caption**, you need to retrieve the attachment post directly, since that info is stored in wp_posts.

So you could do something like this:

```
<?php if( has_post_thumbnail( $post_id ) ):
    $pic_id      = get_post_thumbnail_id();
    $pic         = get_post( $pic_id );
    $caption     = $pic->post_excerpt;
    $image_alt   = get_post_meta( $pic->ID, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true );
    $image_title = $pic->post_title;
    ?>
    <div class="post-image">
        <h4><?php echo $image_title; ?></h4>
        <img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( $pic_id); ?>" alt="<?php echo $image_alt; ?>">
        <span class="description"><?php echo $caption;?></span>
    </div>
<? endif; ?>
```

Change the HTML to suit your needs, I don't know where do you want to display the legend and the title.

Comment: hmm, thanks giving errors atm ill debug and get back to you

Comment: plus 1 il check it out. still getting error but will keep at it

Comment: yeah, hold up ill post what im getting

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\wamp64\www\wordpress\wp-content\themes\assessmentday_2016\single.php on line 40

Comment: That error doesn't seem related to your question. Still, there were a couple of (easily fixable) bugs in my code, so I updated my answer. Try with this, but that error seems to indicate you have a missing quote/curly brace somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

What you probably need is [get_post_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/). Example:

```
$meta_value = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'meta_key_name', true );
```

The `get_the_ID()` will be the Id of the current post. Replace `meta_key_name` with our own meta key